# Is there any Jenkins API to get artifacts name and download it?

Tags: api, jenkins, download, artifact, jenkins-api

I want to ask, If I use jenkins. How can I get all artifacts list and download it, but not from jenkins web interface. I want to make my own web interface for certain goals.

Is there any jenkins API to do this?

Answer (score 9):

According to this answer:
https://superuser.com/questions/587426/download-a-file-from-the-latest-stable-jenkins-build

You can use the Jenkins API to get the list of artifacts:
http://***your.jenkins.server***/job/***your.job***/lastStableBuild/api/xml?tree=artifacts%5BrelativePath%5D

With a script, you can extract the artefact relative path:

[image]

Next, you can build your download URLs like:
http://***your.jenkins.server***/job/***your.job***/lastStableBuild/artifact/***relativePath***

Comment: i would also need to get artifact size. is it possible somehow ?

Answer (score 8):

you can download created artifacts with `curl`:

```
curl -u "${USR}":"${PWD}" $JENKINS'/job/'"${NAM}"/"{$JOB}"'/artifact/*zip*/archive.zip' --output "${NAM}_{$JOB}_archive.zip"
```