# How to get the list of the file names from build artifacts using jenkins rest api?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-api

I am trying to get the list of file names from the build artifacts using jenkins rest api.
This URL `http://your.jenkins.server/job/your.job/lastStableBuild/artifact/relativePath` would download the artifact. Is it possible to get the names of the files contained in the artifact without downloading it using jenkins api?

Suppose,the build artifact contains around 5 text files with names ending with `.config` 
Is it possible to retrieve only the file names ending with `.config` using jenkins API?

Answer (score 2):

I found this jenkins api as useful to get list of artifacts `http://your.jenkins.server/job/your.job/lastStableBuild/api/json?tree=artifacts%5BrelativePath%5D` from (ref: [Is there any Jenkins API to get artifacts name and download it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35920756/is-there-any-jenkins-api-to-get-artifacts-name-and-download-it)) the artifacts then can be retrieved by parsing the JSON object in my application.